# How to Find the Error for Spline Interpolation Without the Original Function?

Tags: interpolation, spline

Most of the literature (e.g.: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~amos/412/lecture-notes/lecture11.pdf) I have consulted thus far indicates how one would determine the error of a cubic when the original function F is known. Suppose if I wanted to determine the maximum error bound of the interpolating function when the original function is unknown, what would this error be?

Comment: Obviously you can't compute the error. Do you want to estimate the error heuristically based on the given function values? Can you chose the step size?

Comment: Yes, I am able to chose the step size. I have been thinking of a heuristic approach but I am not quite sure how to go about doing so. I understand that the exact error can not be computed evidently...but alluding to a Taylor Expansion, in the error term there is a f[k+1 derivative of (z)]. Presumably, the maximum error bound should be situated where  f[k+1 derivative of (z)] = 0. Can something like this be carried over to spline interpolation?

Comment: You are working on the standard cubic spline interpolation problem, don't you? So the error is of order $4$, to be exact some constant $c$ times the uniform norm $M_4$ of the 4th derivative times $h^4$. Say $s_1$ is the spline to step size $h$ and $s_2$ is the spline to step size $2h$. Then, $\| s_1 - s_2 \| \approx c M_4 15 h^4$. so you can use it as **heuristic**.